# Style changes in AngularJs directive is not reflected in the actual element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive written in angularjs 1.5.6, it doesn't update the actual element in the browser, but the element inside the directive gets updated. Can somebody help me solve this issue.

My code is as follows,

```
mccp.directive ('menuFunc', function (){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element) {

        angular.element(element).bind('click', function ($event) {
            $event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
            console.log($event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display);
        });
    }
};
});
```

What I'm actually trying to do is to create a drop down list which works on click.

for example,

```
<ul>
   <li menu-func><a href="#/">Test</a>
      <ul>
         <li>Item1</li>
         <li>Item2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want the next ul shown when a click happens on the list element with the menu-func directive. The update happens properly, because the console log prints the element with the style attached to it, but it's not reflected in the view in browser.

I'm new to angularjs so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code into plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/s01OJjtNvDVSnd1NgXI7?p=preview). I just add style="display: none" on next ul. And I update a little your directive to hide ul if already displayed. Tell me if I understand your question ?

```
<ul>
   <li menu-func>
     <a href="#/">Test</a>
      <ul style="display:none">
         <li>Item1</li>
         <li>Item2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

.directive ('menuFunc', function (){
```

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element) {

```
    angular.element(element).bind('click', function ($event) {
        $event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 
            $event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
        console.log($event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display);
    });
}
};
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. :)
You understood the question correctly, but the code that was there should have worked ... The issue was that I had a hyperlink in the list item where the menuFunc directive is attached, I just had a # there i totally forgot about that ... The problem is every time i click on that element page is getting reloaded, that's why I couldn't see the changes earlier . Anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have another issue with this when i try to apply this to sub lists ... When i click on a sublist which is assigned this menu-func directive, it shows the click twice ... I dont understand why that happens ...
I was able to edit your plunkr to replicate this issue...

Here's the link,
https://plnkr.co/edit/s01OJjtNvDVSnd1NgXI7?p=preview

If you can take a look at it i'd really appreciate it ... thanks in advance :)

Comment: Actually I was able to solve that issue as well... What was happening was something called bubbling. So if you add,

e.stopPropagation();

to the binding function it would work properly :)